# Получение arp таблицы

Tags: c++, boost, asio, arp

Как получить arp-таблицу текущего хоста или как найти mac-адрес по ip-адресу с помощью `boost.asio`? Нужно что-то типа [SendARP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366358(v=vs.85).aspx) функции, только кроссплатформенной. Если это невозможно сделать с помощью `boost.asio`, то посоветуйте подходящую либу.

Comment: так, а чем плох SendARP ? или вам надо кроссплатформа?

Comment: AFAIK в *nix-системах нет специального системного вызова, так что надёжным способом является создание сырого сокета и прямая посылка arp-запроса от процесса, но для этого процесс должен обладать соответствующими правами (мандат cap_net_raw в linux). Более распространённая практика, не требующая самостоятельного повышения прав — вызвать утилиту `arping` и распарсить вывод... короче говоря я подозреваю, что кросс-платформенного маломальски распространённого решения нет...